# Swiftmailer doesn't work anymore [Symfony 2.6.11]

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Last night I reinstalled windows 7. This morning I made a copy of my website into htdocs folder (xampp server). I notified that I'm not anymore receiving a confirmation mail after registration of a user.I did verified everything but it's seems like everything is ok.

I think there is a problem with swiftmailer.

app/config

```
enter code here fos_user:
db_driver:              orm
firewall_name:          main
user_class: FLY\UserBundle\Entity\User
use_listener:           true
#use_flash_notifications: true
use_username_form_type: true
model_manager_name:     null  # change it to the name of your entity/document manager if you don't want to use the default one.
from_email:
    address:       xxxxxxxx@hotmail.fr
    sender_name:    webmaster
profile:
    form:
        type:               fos_user_profile
        name:               fos_user_profile_form
        validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
change_password:
    form:
        type:               fos_user_change_password
        name:               fos_user_change_password_form
        validation_groups:  [ChangePassword, Default]
registration:
    confirmation:
        from_email: # Use this node only if you don't want the global email address for the confirmation email
            address:        xxxxxxxx@hotmail.fr
            sender_name:   Webmaster
        enabled:    true # change to true for required email confirmation
        template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    form:
        type:               fos_user_registration
        name:               fos_user_registration_form
        validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
resetting:
    token_ttl: 86400
    email:
        from_email: # Use this node only if you don't want the global email address for the resetting email
            address:        ...
            sender_name:    ...
        template:   FOSUserBundle:Resetting:email.txt.twig
    form:
        type:               fos_user_resetting
        name:               fos_user_resetting_form
        validation_groups:  [ResetPassword, Default]
service:
    mailer:                 fos_user.mailer.default
    email_canonicalizer:    fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
    username_canonicalizer: fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
    token_generator:        fos_user.util.token_generator.default
    user_manager:           fos_user.user_manager.default
#group:
    #group_class:    ~ # Required when using groups
    #group_manager:  fos_user.group_manager.default
    #form:
        #type:               fos_user_group
        #name:               fos_user_group_form
        #validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
```

Swiftmailer Configuration

```
swiftmailer:
transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
host:       "%mailer_host%"
encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
username:   "%mailer_user%"
password:   "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: xxx
database_user: root
database_password: xxxxxxx
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_encryption: tls
mailer_host: smtp-mail.outlook.com
mailer_user: xxxxxxxx@hotmail.fr
mailer_password: xxxxxxxxx
locale: en
secret: 103615aeafd19ddd60cf64267fbf6b871
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to reply only now. I did check the log and everything is OK. This morning I told myself on the side of xampp server and swiftmailer all seems fine. **Swiftmailer use the port 25 right? i think telkom my service provider block the port 25, because i shared the internet (3G) from my phone to my computer and now it's working perfectly** .Tomorrow i will to the office of telkom, i'm so angry they waste my time for nothing!!!

Thank you so much for your help. see you

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a Swiftmailer issue, after a new Windows install make sure that everything is re-configured to work as before - windows Firewall, anti-viruses, Apache configs, PHP parameters and extensions. It would have been really wise to not just backup your web files but the settings that made it work as well. i.e. you take a Benz engine out of the Benz and fit it into a BMW, if it doesn't work it does not mean the engine has a problem, please recheck your windows environment especially the Error and Access logs of XAMPP.

Comment: Hi Don Omondi, i will check it now. i will let's you know. thank you

Comment: I found my old xampp folder , i replaced the new xampp folder by the old one. i turned off windows Firewall and Avira. But it still not working.